# Correct interpretation "show mls qos"

Tags: cisco-catalyst, qos

I ask you to tell me in the correct interpretation of the output of commands on the Cisco Catalyst 3750.
command

```
"show mls qos interface fastEthernet 0/3 statistics".
```

Outputs the following:

```
output queues enqueued:  
queue: threshold1 threshold2 threshold3

-----------------------------------------------------   
queue 0: 0 0 0    
queue 1: 0 0 5567    
queue 2: 0 0 0    
queue 3: 0 0 157756673
 
output queues dropped:    

queue: threshold1 threshold2 threshold3

-----------------------------------------------------    
queue 0: 0 0 0    
queue 1: 0 0 0    
queue 2: 0 0 0    
queue 3: 0 0 3020372
```

Here we see the "threshold 3" column
but this is not in the output of the command:

```
show mls qos queue-set 2

Queueset: 2 Queue : 1 2 3 4

---------------------------------------------- 
buffers : 1 49 1 49 

threshold1: 100 3200 100 3200 

threshold2: 100 200 100 200 

reserved : 50 100 50 100 

max : 400 3200 400 3200
```

Why?

Just as we see in the first output, the queues begin with numbering zero, and in the second from one, I correctly understand that they are equivalent, i.e. 0=1,1=2 , in turn.

Answer (score 1):

You can only configure threshold1 and threshold2. Threshold3 is always 100% and cannot be configured. Unfortunately, cisco decided to not show the 3rd threshold in any 'show configuration' output.

If you configure following:

```
switch(config)#mls qos queue-set output 2 threshold 1 40 70 80 1000
```

This results in this output:

```
switch#show mls qos queue-set 2       
Queueset: 2
Queue     :       1       2       3       4
----------------------------------------------
buffers   :      10      50      20      20
threshold1:      40     200     100     100
threshold2:      70     200     100     100
reserved  :      80      50      50      50
maximum   :    1000     400     400     400
```

There are 3 thresholds for every queue. This is a bit of cheating in order to use more classes on an interface. MLS QoS on a 3750 has 4 available queues which forces you to reuse already occupied queues if you work with more than 4 classes. With the use of threshold, you can still kind of prioritize certain classes over others while using the same queue. There are 3 thresholds per queue that gives you 12 usable classes. Cisco recommends not to use more than 11 classes wich results in 12 classes in total if you add the unavoidable class-default.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, everything is clear!